# How to combine two sine waves without cracks

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals, sine-wave

I'm using Python, pyaudio and scipy and I would like to combine two sine waves (two tones) in a way that one tone is played after another (create melody). Let's assume that I have two arrays: `tone1` and `tone2`.

`tone1` contains data of sine wave with frequency of 350 Hz. `tone2` contains sine wave's data with frequency of 440 Hz.

My question is: how to combine these two arrays (`tone1` and `tone2`) into one array that, after being played, will give me a melody without noticeable crack between these two sine waves (`tone1` and `tone2`)?

Comment: how are you doing it so far?

Comment: I don't think that code will help here - I just need a general idea how to do it and/or functions that may be helpful.

Comment: Your ear will not notice the crack, just play one tone directly after the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append them together and apply a Fourier Transform smoothing filter. In the regions with a single tone, the Fourier transform will have only one component, and the filter will do nothing; whereas in the transition region you will get both components (plus the crap coming from the jump), that the filter would hopefully smooth out.

Comment: Does numpy/scipy has function to perform Fourier Transform smoothing filtering?

Comment: I don't think they do, but you can use pyOpenCV: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html or roll your own.